position encoding in lsp
Using the language server protocol (lsp) between VS Code and a self implemented language server executable (win, exe, per socket), I am recognising the shipped data format and wondering about the range calculation.
Explaining on an example: In VS Code a document is opened with the text
package aäbc

The first info about the text is:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/didOpen","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///d%3A/dev/test%20files/test_vscode1049-2.fidl","languageId":"francaidl","version":1,"text":"package aÃ¤bc"}}}

Please see the value of text. Then the user selects b after the special character ä (German umlaut) and replaces it at once by xyzÖ (again a special character included).
Looking at the received message, I see
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/didChange","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///d%3A/dev/test%20files/test_vscode1049-2.fidl","version":2},"contentChanges":[{"range":{"start":{"line":0,"character":10},"end":{"line":0,"character":11}},"rangeLength":1,"text":"xyzÃ–"}]}}

I like to set your focus on two things:

The sent text contains some encodings, ä is replaced by Ã¤ (first message didOpen) and Ö is replaced by Ã– (second message didChange).
The start position is set to character=10 (see range/start/character in didChange). So the real letters are
counted.

My conclusion is, that the exchanged text uses UTF-8, but the position counting has the code point (visible letter) in mind - which is quite meaningful, I think. On the other hand it seems that I have to adjust the given range when working with the shipped 8-bit units of UTF-8 - which is quite uncomfortable, I think.
But: In the initialisation process of the lsp we find a property for position encoding. You can presume that my response gave the default value utf-16 back (actually the only item in the request, which is being sent by VS Code and which "must always be supported" according to the specification). So what I am wondering about is (the concrete questions): Should not be the calculation of the range respect positionEncoding anyway? And if not: What is the purpose of positionEncoding?
By the way: Nothing changes if no position encoding is set in the response, because of "If omitted it defaults to 'utf-16'" (again according to the specification).
And I finally want to append, that I checked the transmitted data, which is sent via socket: Wireshark also shows me UTF-8 encoding. Does anybody know if this can and must be adjusted to something else?

Ã¤ and Ã– are not "some encodings", they are just the tool you're using to view/debug the API calls assuming that data is Windows-1252, when its actually UTF-8. See this handy chart: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

@IMSoP Thank you for your response. You are right, bad wording at my side: I wanted to say that some characters of the message are encoded, others are human readable.

There's nothing more or less "human readable" or "encoded" about the different characters, they have all been encoded as UTF-8, then misinterpreted (presumably by whatever tool you're using to debug) as Windows-1252. It just happens that UTF-8 and Windows-1252 agree about how to encode some characters, so it accidentally shows the right thing for those characters. You can't have text that's "not encoded", it's got to be represented as binary somehow. What every programmer needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text
